Definition of the Cartesian product in ZFC
The definition I know is
$$A\times B\triangleq\{x\in\mathscr P(\mathscr P(A\cup B)):\exists u\exists v(x=(u,v))\},$$
whose existence and uniqueness follow from the axioms of separation and extensionality. However, this only works for two sets. How do I define the cartesian product $\mathscr C a$ for a given set $a$?

By $\mathscr{C}a$, I think you mean the cartesian product of all sets that are members of $a$. You can write that as:
$$
\{ f : a \to \bigcup a : \forall x \in a(f(x) \in x)\}.
$$
Normally, we think of a cartesian product of an indexed set of sets, e.g., $\prod_{i=1}^n \Bbb{Z}_i$. If you just have a set of sets, then we can only take that set as giving the indexes.

I don't really see how this is the Cartesian product of $a$ (by the way yeah, that's what I meant by $\mathscr C a$.) Care to explain, please? Also, wouldn't this just be the set of all functions $f\colon a\to a$?

@Elvis Yeah, that's a typo... it should say $f(x)\in x$

@spaceisdarkgreen oh, I see now. $\mathscr C a$ being nonempty for any $a$ is equivalent to the axiom of choice, right?

@Elvis AC is equivalent to $\mathscr{C}a$ being nonempty for any $a$ that doesn't contain the empty set.

@spaceisdarkgreen ah, right, I forgot that. Thank you by the way.

@spaceisdarkgreen: thanks for pointing out the slip in my answer. I have fixed it.
